# MVCContrib TestHelper and User.Identity.Name, Server.MapPath and Form Collection

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am new to MVCContrib Testhelper and mocking with Rhino.

I am needing assistance with unit testing a controller which relies on User.Identity.Name, Server.MapPath and Form Collection.

I started off with

```
var controller = new SubmitController();
var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
builder.InitializeController(controller);
```

I found [this post](http://www.mfranc.com/tag/mvc-contrib/) for setting User.Identity.Name

```
controller.ControllerContext = TestHelper.MockControllerContext(controller).WithAuthenticatedUser("domain\\username");
```

At this point, in my controller i am now able to get to the User.Identity.  The problem then became how to i set Form Collection variables.  Setting

```
builder.Form.Add("testvar","1");
```

no longer worked.  It seemed that now I had to access via

```
controller.HttpContext.Request.Form.Add("testvar","1)
```

This seemed to work, but at this point, i was no longer using builder(TestControllerBuilder) above.

I then had to mock Server which raised up more issues.  How can I continue to use builder but use mocks or stubs for httpContext, HttpRequest, Server etc.  I was sort of expecting that builder would have methods for setting expected values for HttpRequest, Server etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you replaced the controller's `ControllerContext` that removed the MVCContrib context. Try something like this:

```
using MvcContrib.TestHelper;
using MvcContrib.TestHelper.Fakes;
using Rhino.Mocks;

...
var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
builder.Form.Add("testvar", "1"); 
builder.HttpContext.User = new FakePrincipal(new FakeIdentity("UserName"), new string[] { "Role" });
builder.HttpContext.Server.Stub(x => x.MapPath(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return("Value");
builder.InitializeController(controller);
```